# Facebook Graph API v2. Event attendees ID. App scoped id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

After searching the web, I can't seem to find an answer to my question.

Here is the context:

After a user has logged in my app using facebook login, his **user_id** and long-lived token are saved in the database. Afterwards, a query is sent to the Graph API v2 to get his events and those events attendees. Everything works as expected but this app_scope_id is causing me trouble!

Here are my questions:

> 1. Are those attendees IDS app_scoped_id as well ? Or are they global IDS ?
> 2. A user attending an event and a user from the loggin flow will have the same ID ?
> 3. Do these app_scope_id likely to change over time, is it safe to store them in the database ?

Sorry for all these messy questions, but this app_scope_id is disturbing me a bit!

PS: If i I get this thing right, an attendee will not have the same ID on the Graph API Explorer and my app request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not have the same ID. Those are called app-scoped for a reason :-)

Your questions:

1. They should be app-scoped as well
2. They should be the same if you use the same application to request the data
3. I guess they stay the same, because otherwise FB would break existing applications (there's nothing mentioned in the docs afaik though...)